# Find row number where specific words exist in char array

Tags: arrays, matlab, char

I know this is simple and I've tried strmatch, ismember, cellfun variations with no answer that I am looking for.
I have data that looks like this, which are dates in variable "x" 
28-Dec-2014
29-Dec-2014
30-Dec-2014
31-Dec-2014
01-Jan-2015
02-Jan-2015
03-Jan-2015
04-Jan-2015
05-Jan-2015
All I need to know is which row numbers == 'Jan'?  So, the result of analyzing rows in "x" should be 
result = 
5
6
7
8
9

Comment: Please specify the array `x`. Is it cell array, or 2D matrix of the type `char`?

Comment: sorry...actual size(x) = 8797 x 11 in my case...Matlab describes "x" as abc 8797x11 char.  in the example I have given, x is 9 x 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative using regular expressions:

```
clear
clc

X = {'28-Dec-2014' ,'29-Dec-2014', '30-Dec-2014', '31-Dec-2014' ,...
    '01-Jan-2015', '02-Jan-2015' ,'03-Jan-2015', '04-Jan-2015', '05-Jan-2015'}

%// Look for any element in X containing Jan
CheckCells = regexp(X,'Jan')

%// Find non-empty cells, resulting from the call to regexp.
Indices = find(~cellfun('isempty',CheckCells))
```

Output:

```
Indices =

     5     6     7     8     9
```

Comment: Hi - I'm getting this error when I try and run your example on my variable "x" - >> CheckCells = regexp(x,'Jan')
Error using regexp
The 'STRING' input must be a one-dimensional array of char or cell arrays of strings.

Comment: @user2100039 You need to use `cellstr()` there to get X.

Comment: Thanks @Divakar. +1 btw, I always forget to use `strsplit`  and `strcmp` for these kind of tasks.

Comment: One more thing `cellfun('isempty'..)` might be better as that's a builtin.

Answer (score 1):

This could be one approach -

```
%// Convert to cell array
x_cell = cellstr(x_cell)

%// Split each cell into cells based on the delimiter "-"
X_split  = cellfun(@(v) strsplit(v,'-'),x_cell,'Uni',0)

%// Look for "Jan" in the second cell of each cell at the "first level"
idx = find(cellfun(@(v) strcmp(v{2},'Jan'),X_split))
```

Comment: thanks but I'm not clear on the difference of X and x in your example above.  I'm getting an error with an undefined variable.